# Time based cmd exit

Tags: windows, if-statement, time, cmd, compare

I am busy working on a cmd program (using Windows & and running cmd as a Admin) which will do the following:

- Detect all computers connected to a network and write to a text file (This part is functioning correctly)
- Exit the program if the computer time is equal e.g 12:00pm

The program is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF

color a

: Begin

IF %Time% /t GTQ 01:15 && %Time% /t LEQ 01:20 (GOTO END) <---- problem is here

%                                                                                             %
% Date stamp the log entry and copy values. Wait 3 min before redoing the scan and check time %
%                                                                                             %

Time /t >> C:\Users\Paimon\Desktop\"WIFI data.txt"

Date /t >> C:\Users\Paimon\Desktop\"WIFI data.txt"

netstat -n

netstat -n >> C:\Users\Paimon\Desktop\"WIFI data.txt"

timeout /t 180

cls

GOTO Begin

:END
exit
```

I decided that the time should be compared to a raged value since the program only executes that certain line every 3 min.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems in your problematic line:

`%time% /t` won't work

`GTQ` is not an allowed operator (use GTR or GEQ)

You cannot do `if a && b then`

A good solution would be:

```
if %time: =0% geq 01:15 if %time: =0% leq 01:20 goto end
```

Comment: +1, Excellent simple solution to the question asked.

Comment: I am afraid, Stephan, that if I insert your code to my existing code cmd returns the error: 72 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: `72`? Seventy-Two? No chance to get that error with this code. Remove the `@echo off` to see, what happens.